# put a iframe in a center of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put the iframe tag in a middle of the parent div in every size of monitor,I used bootstrap:

```
 <div class="col-md-2  col-sm-2 col-xs-12  animated2 zoomInDown">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="box" style="min-height: 180px; background-color: white">
                            <iframe id="enamad" class="thumbnail meNamad" src="#" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I've tried margin-left:35% in "meNamad" class in css but it just work in xs size that i used col-xs-12 but in other size it's pushed to right

Comment: Please put fiddle demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the parent div position: relative.

Give its child div or the iframe position:absoute; margin auto; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;

no matter how big/small is the parent div the child div will always be in the center wrt parent.

Comment: yes i have problem with this kind of people.but don't worry.you are good... .

Comment: pleasure to help u.;)

Comment: There are so many people here who just try to bring you down.... seriously this is my 3rd account here and i don't want to get blocked because of these silly down voters.